# Spring @Transactional boundaries

Tags: java, spring

I'm using @Transactional in my service layer.  If I annotate two updating service methods with @Transactional (using default settings) and a controller method is calling both of these methods to perform its action, do both service methods use the same transaction?

It appears that they do not, and I am looking for confirmation of this. It would appear to me that to get both methods to use the same transaction I would need to write a third method in the service, annotate it with @Transactional, and call the original two methods from there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

everything you said is correct, including how to get around the issue.  It might be a good time to implement a Facade service that coordinates all your other services.  That way the the used services will participate in the transactions of the Facade service.

Comment: Agreed, except it isn't a flaw, so I wouldn't call it an "issue." There are times when you want to call two service methods that each run in thier own transaction. For example, suppose one service call completes a purchase and the second decides which ad to show at the edge of the user's browser window based on which ads they've seen. You wouldn't want to roll back the purchase if the ad logic fails; you'd want to show a purchase complete screen with a fallback ad.

Comment: @gatkin of course.  I meant 'issue' in the sense of "what the OP was struggling with"

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. In my case I have a web page that collects a lot of information about one person (name, addresses, phone numbers, etc.).  The controller was making calls to various service methods to handle all of the persists.  It's looking like I need to encapsulate what the controller is doing into a single @Transactional service method, and simply call that method from the controller, passing in all the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds correct to me.  But you should also think whether or not those two methods should have default settings for Transaction propagation. See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) and decide if it should be 'REQUIRED' or 'SUPPORTS' ?
example: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)